# Bootstrap3 300x250 banner in col-md-3 or col-md-4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We use `bootstrap3` with basic two-columns layout. Left column's class is `col-md-9`, right is `col-md-3` as well.

However,we have a problem when we want to place a banner to right column.

For a common ad-banner `(300x250px)`, `col-md-3` is small `(width is 261px)` and `col-md-4` is large `(359px)`

How can we fix `col-md-3` to `300px` by keeping bootstrap's all responsive features?

Is there any common approach to do this?

Comment: Please add a sketch of your design. Is resize the banner allowed? On the first sight in say add a class img-responsive to your banner. Or a pull-right class in your col-md-4.

Answer (score 0):

In your case probably better to change the default 12 columns grid to 16 columns( or maybe other)

Try to change variables below:

```
// Number of columns in the grid system
@grid-columns:              12;
// Padding, to be divided by two and applied to the left and right of all columns
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
```

For example:
right - 5 columns
left - 9 columns